# Delete a layer in Openlayers

Tags: asp.net, openlayers

I added a markers by adding layer in OpenLayers.
I use it in my asp project and I load a map and I can add multi icons.
Now I load my locations and show them by that icons.
My code is like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < loc.length; i++) {
        LocationArray.push(loc[i]);
        iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(loc[i])),
            name: 'Null Island',
            population: 4000,
            rainfall: 500
        });
        iconFeatures.pop();
        debugger
        iconFeatures.push(iconFeature);
        vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: iconFeatures //add an array of features
        });

        iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.5, 100],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 0.8,
                src: '/images/icon.png',

            }))
        });
        vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: iconStyle
        });

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    }
```

Now I want to Delete this layer when I click on it.
I can detect where is it clicked and I response it but I don't know how I can delete it.
My code is like this:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
            return feature;
        });
        if (feature) {
            var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            if (confirm("Do you want to delete?")) {
                
              // What should I code here?

            }
        } else {
          // .....
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `forEachFeatureAtPixel` callback can also receive the layer, if you save that it is easy to remove the layer:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
        var vectorLayer;
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature, layer) {
            vectorLayer = layer;
            return feature;
        });
        if (feature) {
            var coordinates = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            if (confirm("Do you want to delete?")) {
                
              map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);

            }
        } else {
          // .....
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the layer but remove the markers you can use the clear() method.

```
vectorLayer.getSource().clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response
I've found it by `map.removeLayer(layer);` code